# Type-error clientsettings.userStore is not a function with ng-oidc-client JS lib

Tags: javascript, angular, typeerror, openid-connect

I am using the ng-oidc-client package to integrate my auth server with an angular Website. Note I am using Angular 7 and latest version of node.

The version of ng-oidc-client is 1.0.5, which is fairly latest. the peer dependencies of this library are also latest. Upon running, I get the below error which mostly to me looks like a incompatibility issue.

[image: Error]

Code snippet - 
This is the code from my appModule.ts where the oidc client module config is set up -

```
NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
        oidc_config: {
          authority: 'https://xxxxx.com.au/authentication',
          client_id: 'Paystay.localwebsite',
          userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
          redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:4200/callback.html',
          response_type: 'id_token',
          scope: 'openid profile',
          post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:4200/signout-callback.html',
          silent_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:4200/renew-callback.html',
          accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60,
          automaticSilentRenew: true,
        },
        log: {
          logger: console,
          level: Log.NONE
        }
    }),
```

Please note that I have masked the Authority URI here.
Rest of the code is pretty standard for integrating this client on Angular 2 which i followed from this link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-oidc-client

Update - The issue seems to be not there with version 1.0.0 of the lib. I have raised a issue with the author and waiting for the response.

Comment: Could you upload source code to https://stackblitz.com/ so I can take a look ?

Comment: You need to include source code to the question

Comment: Without code nobody could help you

Answer (score 2):

The configuration for ng-oidc-client is the only traceable cause that could be derived with the currently provided information.

Recheck by defining the [optional settings](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki#other-optional-settings) property `userStore` to the value `new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })` else upload the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with the `ng-oidc-client`.
I tried to use the optional parameters from the underlying library, but they're not available from the `NgOidcClientModule`.
I wrapped the creation of the userStore in a function.

```
NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
  oidc_config: {
    authority: `${window.location.origin}/auth/realms/xxx`,
    client_id: 'xxxxxx',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile offline_access roles',
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/callback.html`,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/signout-callback.html`,
    silent_redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/renew-callback.html`,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    userStore: () => new WebStorageStateStore({store: window.localStorage}),
  },
})
```